# Calculate Gain Loss Excel Percentage

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've tried many ways of getting the percentage but it will not work for Gain/Loss

```
╭──────────────╥────────┬────────╥────────╮
│              ║ Jan    │ Feb    │ Mar    │
╞══════════════╬════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ Amount       ║ 100    │ 1000   │ 100    │
├──────────────╫────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ Change %     ║ 0      │ -88%   │ 733%   │ C2/B2-1
╞══════════════╬════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ Amount       ║ 300000 │ 9000   │ 300000 │
├──────────────╫────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ Change %     ║ 0      │ -97%   │ 3233%  │ C4/B4-1    
╰──────────────╨────────┴────────┴────────╯
```

How can I get the correct result with Gain/Loss? as -97% can't be if the opposite is 3233%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reversed it, I made it into an if function, if anyone else is wanting to know how to get a steady Plus/Minus from Gains and Losses this formula worked for me

```
=IF(C4<=B4,1-B4/C4,C4/B4-1)
```

Comment: So, for example, going from 75 to 25 you want your result to be -200%?

Comment: Yes, as that is the correct actual loss -200%, and 25 to 25 is 0%, so no gains and 25 to 50 is 100%, we doubled our gains, and 25 to 75 is 200%

Comment: Well I understand if that works for your needs/definition but I have to say, going from 75 to 25 is not a loss of 200% in any traditional mathematical sense.

Comment: if that is not 200%, then what should the correct actual loss be?

Comment: From 75 to 25 is a loss of 66.67%. From 25 to 75 is a gain of 200%.